# Group Entry Listing By Channel

Tags: channel-entries, orderby

I feel like there's an obvious answer to this, but is it possible to have one channel entries tag with multiple channels and group the output by channel? For example:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog|news|press_releases"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="50"
    orderby="channel"
}
    {!-- All Blog Entries First --}

    {!-- All News Entries Second --}

    {!-- All Press Releases Entries Third --}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Please, help me to understand. Why not to use three exp:channel:entries?

Comment: It looks like she wants to limit the entries to the 50 most recent between these channels. Separating would make that count hard to achieve dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Textbook use case for Stash:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog|news|press_releases"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="50"
}
  {exp:stash:append_list name="entries" context="{channel_short_name}"}
    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
  {/exp:stash:append_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}

<ul>
{exp:stash:get_list name="entries" context="blog" process="end"}
  <li><a href="{path='blog/{url_title}'}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="entries" context="news" process="end"}
  <li><a href="{path='news/{url_title}'}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="entries" context="press_releases" process="end"}
  <li><a href="{path='press_releases/{url_title}'}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd always look to go this route with Stash too.

Comment: I tried setting it up just like this, and the template debugger shows the Stash variables being created, but no entries are being returned between the `get_list` tags. I'm a Stash n00b, so I don't really know how to troubleshoot. Suggestions?

Comment: For `process="end"` to work you need to be using the latest Stash (2.3.6), EE 2.4 or later and have the Stash extension installed.

Comment: Also, you should use `{exp:stash:append_list}` to capture the entry data since the Stash tags are nested inside the channel entries tag pair rather than wrapped around it.

Comment: OK, I edited Rob's code above as I spotted a mismatched tagpair too.

Comment: @mark-croxton Ah ha. Yes, updating to 2.3.6, enabling the extension, and changing the tags to `{exp:stash:append_list}` did it. I should also mention that I had to set `parse_tags='yes'` and `parse_conditionals='yes'` for my particular code block to work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like,

```
{if channel_id=="Blog Entries ID #"} Content {/if}
{if channel_id==" News Entries ID #"} Content {/if}
```

etc. etc?

I do believe that the order of the conditionals top to bottom will output which you want to go first, next, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would still output the entries by date. I'd use something like that if I needed to output different code per-channel (like I wanted blog entries to be red, and news entries to be green). So what that's saying is "if the entry you're about to output is in the blog channel, use this code".

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it, you can use a small query to get the channel name and passing one by one in channel entry tag like:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT channel_name FROM exp_channels WHERE channel_name IN ('blog', 'news', 'press_releases') ORDER BY FIELD(channel_name,'blog', 'news', 'press_releases')"}

{exp:channel:entries
    channel="{channel_name}"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="50"
    orderby="channel"
}

###### entries ########

{/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:query}
```

I hope, it would help you.